# Boost: how to use `boost::hash` with `std::pair`, when pair contains a custom type?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, boost

I'm trying to use the following custom `unordered_map`

```cpp
using pair = std::pair<char, QColor>;
using cache = std::unordered_map<pair, QPixmap, boost::hash<pair>>;
cache _cache;
```

I defined the hash function for QColor as follows

```cpp
template<>
struct std::hash<QColor>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const QColor &color) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<QRgb>{}(color.rgb());
    }
};
```

but no matter where I place it, whether it is a header or source file, I get a verbose compile time error from boost

```
C:\boost_1_77_0\boost\container_hash\extensions.hpp:305: error: C2665: 'boost::hash_value': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
C:\boost_1_77_0\boost/container_hash/hash.hpp(550): note: could be 'size_t boost::hash_value(const std::error_condition &)'
C:\boost_1_77_0\boost/container_hash/hash.hpp(543): note: or       'size_t boost::hash_value(const std::error_code &)'
C:\boost_1_77_0\boost/container_hash/hash.hpp(536): note: or       'size_t boost::hash_value(std::type_index)'
C:\boost_1_77_0\boost/container_hash/extensions.hpp(305): note: while trying to match the argument list '(const T)'
```

It is the last message of all. I think that boost's hashing function for pair doesn't see the hash function I defined. Do I need define it in the boost's namespace? And in general, what's the rule for defining the specific versions of templates? Why the rule that the templates must be defined in header files only doesn't apply here?

UPD: The structure of my project is as follows

```
// foo.h
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

#include <unordered_map>

template<>
struct std::hash<QColor>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const QColor &color) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<QRgb>{}(color.rgb());
    }
};

class Foo
{
private:
    using Pair = std::pair<char, QColor>;
    const QPixmap &getPixmapForPair(Pair c);

    using CharsCache = std::unordered_map<Pair, QPixmap, boost::hash<Pair>>;
    CharsCache _cache;
}
```

```
// foo.cpp
const QPixmap &Foo::getPixmapForPair(Pair c)
{
    auto it = _cache.find(c);
    if (it != _cache.end())
        return it->second;
}
```

Very oversimplified, but delivers the general idea.

Comment: Can you try [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6bsjEEn1Y)? I don't have MSVC + Qt + boost available so I can't verify it myself, but when mocking the Qt types it works for me in MSVC. If I remove the mocks it works fine in `g++` and `clang++`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Strange, but it does work for me with both mocks and real Qt types in a single source file - the one you provided. But when it comes to my project with a more complex structure - I receive the error in the question. I'll update my question with my project structure explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::hash<>` probably uses `boost::hash_combine` which uses `hash_value` overloads and it doesn't have one for `QColor` which could be a problem so I suggest that you create a specialization for `std::hash<Pair>` by moving the alias out of the class definition and then use `boost::hash_combine` directly in your `operator()`:

```
using Pair = std::pair<char, QColor>;

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<Pair> {
        std::size_t operator()(const Pair &p) const noexcept {
            std::size_t seed = 0;
            boost::hash_combine(seed, p.first);
            boost::hash_combine(seed, p.second.rgb());
            return seed;
        }
    };
} // namespace std
```

You could probably make it `std::size_t seed = p.first;` instead of initializing with `0` and calling `hash_combine` afterwards.

You can then use the default hasher (`std::hash<Pair>`) when creating your map:

```
class Foo {
private:
    const QPixmap &getPixmapForPair(const Pair &c) const;

    using CharsCache = std::unordered_map<Pair, QPixmap>;
    CharsCache _cache;
};
```

Note that the function must return a value. I suggest that you throw an exception if it can't find a match:

```
const QPixmap& Foo::getPixmapForPair(const Pair &c) const {
    auto it = _cache.find(c);
    if (it != _cache.end()) return it->second;
    throw std::runtime_error("getPixmapForPair"); // must return a value
}
```

---

Another option is to provide an overload for `hash_value(const QColor&)` instead of a specialization for `std::hash<Pair>`:

```
std::size_t hash_value(const QColor& c) {
    return std::hash<QRgb>{}(c.rgb());
}

class Foo {
private:
    using Pair = std::pair<char, QColor>;
    const QPixmap& getPixmapForPair(const Pair& p) const;

    using CharsCache = std::unordered_map<Pair, QPixmap, boost::hash<Pair>>;
    CharsCache _cache;
};
```

Comment: Where is it better to the particular definition of `hash`? I feel like the only right place is before the class definition in the header. But why? And yes, sorry, I indeed return the value from the function which uses the pair, just forgot to include the code when I was simplifying it.

Comment: @sauce The definition of `std::hash<QColor>`? Before you use it I would say is a good place. Note that I added a simpler solution to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: "_I indeed return the value from the function_" - Yes, but only if you find a match.

Comment: I meant that there is a code which I didn't provide.